# How to add properties to native functons/objects like Boolean?

Tags: typescript

Basically pre-Typescript era, the following could be done:

```js
Boolean.prototype.foo = function() {
  console.log(`I am boolean ${this}.`)
}

let truth = Boolean(true)
let lie = Boolean(false)

typeof truth // boolean
typeof lie // boolean

truth.foo() // I am boolean true
lie.foo() // I am boolean false
```

If the above is done in TypeScript, it will produce error since native `Boolean` does not have prop `foo`.

Normally, one would use `class`, but it instantiates an object. The below example shows that it cannot behave in the same way as altering the `#Boolean` prototype directly:

```
class MutatedBoolean extends Boolean {
    foo = () => {}
    constructor(value, foo) {
        super(value)
        this.foo = foo
    }
}

let lie = new MutatedBoolean(!1, () { console.log(`I am boolean ${this}.`) })

typeof lie // object
```

Which cannot be used as a conditional statement like:

```
if (lie)
```

How would we do the same in TypeScript? Or is it not recommended at all?

Comment: If it's you who makes a decision: please **DO NOT**. It's confusing and hard to debug and maintain.

Comment: are you able to elaborate how is this difficult to debug and maintain?

Comment: Ok, let's say you see the following expression: `v.fooBar()` - explain your steps to find where the `fooBar` declaration comes from? (let's assume `v` is of a boolean type)

Comment: hmm I think I can roughly understand that it's not very common in other languages? It's actually not an uncommon practice in Javascript to attach properties to prototypes, and can be quite easily found when in debugging mode by stepping in and out, or ctrl+f "fooBar". It's so common that many popular frames provide ways to extend the base prototype. Before the days of Object.create, Douglas Crockford proposed attaching methods for object creation: https://www.crockford.com/javascript/prototypal.html

Comment: My question was about how you would do it without running code with debugger. In other words - how you would statically analyse it. "It's actually not an uncommon practice in Javascript to attach properties to prototypes" --- frequency of use does not make it good. Having just a function does not make it any worse.

Comment: "It's so common that many popular frames provide ways to extend the base prototype" --- examples? "Crockford proposed attaching methods for object creation" --- it was 14 years ago, when JS was a different language. Now we have better tools to write clear and expressive code (eg. classes).

Comment: alright my view is that given the flexibility of javascript, it is not unusual that when compared to other languages, certain practices can appear odd. There are many things JS programmers and big frameworks even do that they shouldn't, but not this. This particular flexibility (extending base prototype), however, given it benefits, has for many years not been the main issue of code smell with javascript.  When you ask for examples, there are really many -- jQuery is one of them. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of TypeScript you need to declare new properties in a global declaration file (e.g. global.d.ts):

```
declare global {
  interface Boolean {
    foo: () => void;
  }
}
```

Make sure this file is included in the project (in the tsconfig.json)